# Users in MySQL have too many rights

Tags: 12.04, users, phpmyadmin, sql

I finally found out how to install phpmyadmin and get a working internet connection in virtual box after a lot of research. Now, I addes users and gave them specific rights for testing purposes. The problem is when I test the privileges out it seems like they can do anything they want. If I revoke the right to delete databases they can still do it even though I did FLUSH PRIVILEGES; after.

Comment: Are you sure, they don't use sa without password?

Comment: what do you mean by sa?

Comment: Sorry, for MySQL it's root. Is there a password for root?

Answer (score 0):

There might be anonymous user (with blank username) with some rights and all others inherits this privs. Or some rights may be granted in a non-standart way.

Inspect mysql system tables directly, start from

```
SELECT * FROM mysql.user\G
SELECT * FROM mysql.db\G
SELECT * FROM mysql.host\G
```